# Grails: Defining a JSON custom marshaller as static method in domain

Tags: json, grails, marshalling, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I'm using Grails 2.4.2. As can be seen here:

https://grails.org/Converters+Reference

You can create a static method in your domain with your custom marshaller to render the JSON in the controller. Like that:

Domain:

```
// a class to output in JSON
    package com.sample
    class User {
       String login
       String passwd

       // JSON definition of the User object
       static {
          grails.converters.JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(User) {
             return [
                     login: it.login
             ]
            }

    }
```

Then in your controller:

```
def user = new User(login:'bob', passwd:'1234')
render user as JSON
```

**This is not working for me** in my project. I render it and outputs as the default rendering (with class:"com.sample.User"...). **But if I change something in the domain and the environment "reloads" it (recompiling), then the render is OK**.

Of course, I want the custom marshaller code to be in the domain, and if it's possible with no more other code outside (BootStrap.groovy, resources.groovy...) etc, I know how to do custom marshaller the other way (like here: http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/)

So... what i missed? Is it possible?

Comment: I found that this worked when I did it with command objects (i.e. not domain classes) but it didn't work with domain objects when doing as you're doing (Grails 2.4.3).  My domain objects were in a plugin and so I added the `JSON.registerObjectMarshaller()` method to the plugin's `doWithApplicationContext` closure within the `MyPluginGrailsPlugin.groovy` file.  Would love to know whether you managed to fix this.

Comment: No, I didn't. I worked during a short period in this Grails project and I was wondering why this simple example was failing, but I'm not interested anymore. I'd suggest to file a bug report in the Grails project.